# How to get unique rows by multiple column values?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get unique time card rows from a TIMECARD table.

This is what what the Time card table looks like:

```
DATE - LEADER - PROJECT - CARDREVISION
```

```
08/06/2019 - RJONES - 101 - 0
08/06/2019 - RJONES - 101 - 1
08/06/2019 - RJONES - 101 - 2
08/04/2019 - JWILLS - 102 - 0
08/06/2019 - RJONES - 103 - 0
```

As you can see with the CARDREVISION, RJONES has made 2 changes to his time card, for project 101 on Aug 6. Even though the table has 3 distinct records for each of his changes, there is still only one time card for RJONES on AUG 6 for project 101.

How can I do a select statement to get me distinct values for the individual time cards that would be on this table, where it would show the highest value of the CARDREVISION?

Here is what I would want to see:

```
DATE - LEADER - PROJECT - CARDREVISION
```

```
08/06/2019 - RJONES - 101 - 2
08/04/2019 - JWILLS - 102 - 0
08/06/2019 - RJONES - 103 - 0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select DATE, LEADER, PROJECT, max(CARDREVISION)
from t
group by DATE, LEADER, PROJECT;
```

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.DATE, t.LEADER, t.PROJECT, t.CARDREVISION
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where LEADER = t.LEADER and CARDREVISION > t.CARDREVISION
)
```

If you want to the latest revision for each day:

```
select t.DATE, t.LEADER, t.PROJECT, t.CARDREVISION
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where LEADER = t.LEADER and DATE = t.DATE and CARDREVISION > t.CARDREVISION
)
```